# Mux API : Get asset id after upload in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the following script in python which successfully uploads a video to Mux using the Mux Python API Wrapper (https://github.com/muxinc/mux-python) -

```
media = file_name
create_asset_request = mux_python.CreateAssetRequest(playback_policy=[mux_python.PlaybackPolicy.PUBLIC])
create_upload_request = mux_python.CreateUploadRequest(timeout=3600, new_asset_settings=create_asset_request, cors_origin="")
create_upload_response = uploads_api.create_direct_upload(create_upload_request)
assert create_upload_response != None
assert create_upload_response.data != None
assert create_upload_response.data.id != None
print(create_upload_response.data.id)
with open(media, 'rb') as finput:
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.put(create_upload_response.data.url, data=finput)
```

I would now like to get the ID of the newly created asset - there are several methods including GetAssetPlaybackIDResponse (https://github.com/muxinc/mux-python/blob/master/docs/GetAssetPlaybackIDResponse.md) but little documentation on how this can be used.

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by using the .get_direct_upload method on the upload ID:

```
upload_response = uploads_api.get_direct_upload(create_upload_response.data.id)

assert upload_response != None
assert upload_response.data.id != None
assert upload_response.data.id == create_upload_response.data.id

assetId = upload_response.data.asset_id
print(assetId)
```